Trapping a muon in a box with electrons
I was motivated to ask this by considering the fact that a free neutron is unstable - it decays into a proton, electron and an antineutrino with a half-life of a few minutes. However, when a neutron is in an atomic nucleus, it does not decay, because the resulting proton would occupy a high energy shell.
Similarly, a muon can decay into an electron, a neutrino and an antineutrino. However, I wonder whether we can stabilise it by a similar mechanism. Suppose that we have a box full of $N$ electrons and one muon. If the muon were to decay, the resulting electron would have to occupy the lowest unoccupied energy level, so it seems conceivable that for a high enough $N$, this would cost more energy than the decay would produce and the muon would be stable. Does this reasoning make sense?

Related: Possibility of stable muonic structures?, Stable muon density inside a white dwarf star?
